# Загружаю файл с gitHab и, после сборки, возникает проблема

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, обработка-ошибок

Загружаю файл с Github и, после сборки, возникает проблема (тот же самый проект, не скаченный с Github работает корректно):

[image: android]

Comment: А где проблема-то? В чём она выражается?

Comment: @ woesss, после запуска приложения некоторые его функции работали не корректно, вот я и подумал, что дело в этих зачёркнутых значках

Comment: Серые значки означают что некоторые этапы сборки пропущены за ненадобностью - например, код проекта не изменился с прошлой сборки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закройте проект, затем переименуйте папку проекта, убрав из названия -master и всё заработает